# How to get Windows Task Scheduler to resume repeating the task every X minutes?

Tags: windows-server-2012

I'm on Windows Server 2012 and I have a task that runs

- at startup
- at task creation / modification

Both tasks are set to also repeat every 5 minutes, indefinitely.

If I disable the task and then re-enable it, and then run it manually, it never repeats. It only runs that one time.

How can I make my task start running every 5 minutes again? Or am I doing a "run every 5 minutes" thing the wrong way?

I come from a linux/cron background and having to use Windows Scheduler really makes my heart ache =\

Comment: What's the output of: schtasks.exe /Query /TN "foldername\task name" /V /FO LIST   ? This would show us what your current settings are

Comment: What happens if you restart the 'Task Scheduler' service?